# VSIX - dynamic menu with submenus

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

This article explains how it is possible to dynamically add buttons to a menu group in a VSIX Visual Studio extension.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/dynamically-adding-menu-items?view=vs-2019

What the article doesn't explain, and we could also not find it somewhere else, is how we can add other submenus or groups to an existing menu. In other words we would like to dynamically provision a menu with multiple levels. Not only the children in an existing group.
Does somebody know if this is possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

In my Favorite Documents extension I predefine 40*40 groups for submenus in .vsct and then dynamically make them visible and set text as needed.

(Not pretty at all, but works to some extent.)

Comment: Some source code to see how you dynamically show hide the items ?

Comment: @Softlion DefaultInvisible in .vsct and when needed add a command that in BeforeQueryStatus sets menuCommand.Visible = true.

Comment: Is it possible to have a dynamic menu containing dynamic submenus (ie: multiple levels ?). It seems not possible.